# How can I delete my Arqade account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is there a way to permanently delete an Arqade/Gaming Stack Exchange account?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete your account, [this help center article](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) explains how to do so.

Basically, if you've not posted or voted more than once, you can (on most sites) click the "delete profile" link that should be on your profile page.

If you've voted/posted more than once, you will need to [contact the Stack Exchange team](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/contact), selecting the "I need to delete my profile" link and explaining your situation. They'll then reply with further instructions on how to do so.